# Scrapy: ImportError: No module named scrapy_proxies

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I have installed scrapy_proxies with pip install scrapy_proxies. But whenever I run my spider I get the following error log:

```
scrapy crawl event -o items_new.csv
2018-09-13 01:15:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: allevents)
2018-09-13 01:15:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) - [GCC 5.4.0 20160609], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Linux-4.15.0-33-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
2018-09-13 01:15:19 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'allevents.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'items_new.csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['allevents.spiders'], 'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408], 'BOT_NAME': 'allevents', 'RETRY_TIMES': 10, 'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 2300, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'}
2018-09-13 01:15:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-09-13 01:15:19 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2018-09-13 01:15:19 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 98, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/home/hp/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named scrapy_proxies
```

But even in the spider directory, I explicitly tried to install scrapy_proxy and it showed that scrapy_proxies is already installed.

Also,

```
 hp@hp-HP-Notebook:~$  pip --version
    pip 9.0.1 from /home/hp/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Comment: Did you use the same python binary to install scrapy and scrapy_proxy ? Is it scrapy_proxy or scrapy_proxies ?

Comment: Can you also include the output of `pip --version` (assuming you did `pip install scrapy_proxy`)

Comment: It is scrapy_proxies. I installed scrapy in my machine 1 year back. So can't remember now. what to do then?

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/hp/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: See, your `pip` is using python3.6 while your `scrapy` is using python2.7. Try installing the dependency with `python2 -m pip install scrapy_proxies` and then run your scrapy command again.

Comment: Or better yet, try running scrapy with python3, e.g. `python3 -m scrapy crawl event -o items_new.csv`

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r : didn't work

Comment: Kindly edit the question & include what did you try (new) & what you got as unexpected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install scrapy_proxies
```

this will install scrapy_proxies module in your enviroment:

```
Collecting scrapy_proxies
  Downloading scrapy-proxies-0.4.tar.gz (2.3 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: scrapy-proxies
  Building wheel for scrapy-proxies (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel ...
Successfully built scrapy-proxies
Installing collected packages: scrapy-proxies
Successfully installed scrapy-proxies-0.4
```